# Forward port to public host interface in Vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vagrant, portforwarding

Having an Ubuntu 16.04 testserver without GUI, I want to make ports from Vagrant machines accessable to the host from outside, so that I can access them on my Ubuntu dev VM like this:

```
[Dev-VM] <---> [Testserver] <---> [Vagrant-Machine]
```

For this purpose, I added a port forwarding for port 80. This works well with curl from the Testserver, but not from the Dev-VM. Found [`host_ip` in the docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html#host_ip) and tried this:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80, host_ip: "0.0.0.0"
```

Also tried

```
config.vm.network "public_network"
```

but same result:
I can access the test webserver in the Vagrant-Machine and on the Testserver with curl, but not from my Dev-VM. In my understanding, the `host_ip: "0.0.0.0"` should bind port 80 from the VM to any interface on the host, so it should be accessable from other machines in the same network.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would like to warn you to be very careful with the "public network" config because Vagrant boxes are insecure by default, featuring public passwords, insecure keypairs for SSH access, and potentially allow root access over SSH.

It is a little unclear to me what you are attempting to do. If I have understood correctly, you would like to access your Vagrant-Machine from your Dev-VM and *that these are on the same network*.

Here is a link to the documentation for private networks: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html#dhcp .

The easiest would be to allow DHCP to give you an available IP adress like such

```
config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
```

You can determine the given ip by running `vagrant ssh` and then running `ifconfig`

Hope this helps, best regards